# greenlet.error: cannot switch to a different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, greenlets

I have a Flask application, getting this error while trying to integrate flask with [faust](https://github.com/robinhood/faust).

app.py

```
import mode.loop.eventlet
import logging
import logging.config
import json
from flask import Flask
from elasticapm.contrib.flask import ElasticAPM

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    configure_apm(app)
    configure_logging()
    register_blueprints(app)
    register_commands(app)
    return app
```

main.py

```
from flask import jsonify
from litmus.app import create_app
from intercepter import Intercepter

app = create_app()
app.wsgi_app = Intercepter(app.wsgi_app , app)

@app.route('/status')
def status():
    return jsonify({'status': 'online'}), 200
```

another controller

```
@api_blue_print.route('/v1/analyse', methods=['POST'])
def analyse():
    analyse_with_historic_data.send(value=[somedata])
    return jsonify({'message': 'Enqueued'}), 201
```

analyse_with_historic_data.py

```
@app.agent(analysis_topic)
async def analyse_with_historic_data(self, stream):
    async for op in stream:
        entity_log = EntityLog.where('id', op.entity_log_id).first()
```

Error Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahilpaudel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 461, in fire_timers
    timer()
  File "/Users/sahilpaudel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/timer.py", line 59, in __call__
    cb(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/sahilpaudel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/semaphore.py", line 147, in _do_acquire
    waiter.switch()
greenlet.error: cannot switch to a different thread
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahilpaudel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 461, in fire_timers
    timer()
  File "/Users/sahilpaudel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/timer.py", line 59, in __call__
    cb(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/sahilpaudel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/semaphore.py", line 147, in _do_acquire
    waiter.switch()
greenlet.error: cannot switch to a different thread
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahilpaudel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/queue.py", line 118, in switch
    self.greenlet.switch(value)
greenlet.error: cannot switch to a different thread
^CError in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahilpaudel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 551, in wait
    signaled = self._cond.wait(timeout)
  File "/Users/sahilpaudel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 299, in wait
    gotit = waiter.acquire(True, timeout)
  File "/Users/sahilpaudel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/semaphore.py", line 107, in acquire
    hubs.get_hub().switch()
  File "/Users/sahilpaudel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 298, in switch
    return self.greenlet.switch()
  File "/Users/sahilpaudel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 350, in run
    self.wait(sleep_time)
  File "/Users/sahilpaudel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/kqueue.py", line 96, in wait
    time.sleep(seconds)
```

I have trying to fix this issue by monkey.patch_all but that too it didn't work out giving another stacktrace that lock cannot be released something.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something similar happened to me when I tried to debug a flask application using Pycharm.

What I finally did to eventually solve my issue was to enable gevent compatibility in Pycharm:
File -> settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Python debugger -> Gevent compatible

Comment: In vscode the same can be done by adding `"gevent": true` in your `launch.json`. See documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_gevent).

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexTelon . I've been a while looking for some answers for that issue, but yours is the simplest.

Comment: @alex-telon it seems TS is using `eventlet`. Are you sure that `"gevent": true` is correct config? But it's really works for me with eventlet.

Comment: @Kuznetsov-M I am not sure. But if I remember it correctly I was also using `eventlet` not `gevent`. And OP here used `greenlet`. I assume these utilities work in a similar way which is why this flag worked for me too.

Comment: I had a similar issue and that solved it, but now I can't debug my python code normally

Answer (score 1):

If previous answer do not help, paste the following before all imports:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

See here: https://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.monkey.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).